# Python json always fails at first time

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to format a json file using python.

the actually json file I have, looks like this:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-08-01T00:17:04.301Z","name":"name","message":"EndPoint Operation","deviceAction":"Blocked"}{"@timestamp":"2021-08-01T00:26:35.250Z","name":"name","deviceAction":"DENIED"}
```

As you can see the file format is not correct as is missing the comma.

so I have this function to add commas and make it an array of objects.

```
def structure_json():
    with open("./zip/file.json", "r+") as f:
        old = f.read()
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        f.write(old.replace('}{', '},{'))
        tmps = '[' + str(old) + ']'
        json_string = json.loads(tmps)
        for key in json_string:
            to_queue.append(key)
        f.close

structure_json()
```

the script does exactly what I need him to do, it does add the commas and the array, but for some reason. if I put a new json file with the same issue and I run my scripts, it does fail, giving this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 119 (char 118)
```

this is related at the first line of the json. I do believe that this issue is due to the `f.read()` which is the first to be called, and at that given time the json is not formatted. But even if it does fail, and I open the file, I see that has been formatted correctly, so if I run again the script, everything works just fine.

Can anyone help me to go through this issue please? because the function I have is just the first element of a series of events that need to occur after formatting the file, and I can run the scrip twice every time.

Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not saving the replaced value back to the old variable it still contains the incorrect json

```
def structure_json():
    with open("./zip/file.json", "r+") as f:
        old = f.read()
        f.seek(0)  # rewind
        # save to the old string after replace
        new = old.replace('}{', '},{')
        f.write(new)
        tmps = '[' + str(new) + ']'
        json_string = json.loads(tmps)
        for key in json_string:
            to_queue.append(key)
        f.close

structure_json()
```

Comment: even with that I am getting the same issue. it does fail the first time

Comment: ah no so sorry, my mistake. is working. I didn't fully updated my function. Thank you so much